# Solving this recursion question

Tags: recursion

[image: q1]

Text-only

> For the sequence $10,50,250,1250,\ldots$
>
> 1. Determine the first form $a$ and the common ratio $r$.
> 2. Infer an explicit formula for this sequence.
> 3. Write its recursive form.

Please check, if answer is correct?
If wrong, please show correct step to do?

Comment: I don't see the answer for (2). Where is the explicit formula?

Answer (score 1):

Your answers under (1) and (3) are correct .

To answer second question :

Explicit formula for this sequence is :

$a_n=2\cdot 5^n$ with $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

Your work is correct. Note that your recurrence relation needs an initial condition. In this case,

$$ U_1 = 10.$$